# getpeername() returns my local host address when client is running on virtual machine

Tags: c++, sockets, vmware

- I am running my application server on my local machine and an application client on a Virtual Machine (Windows Server 2012).
- I am using the NAT network settings.

When I call the `getpeername()` from the server, I am getting the host machine address and **not the virtual machine address**. Client and Server are running on different domains.

I am a bit confused why this `getpeername()` always returns my local host address when my client is communicating from the Virtual Machine (on a different domain).

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Since you are using NAT the server can not see the real address of the client. If you would do a packet capture (wireshark or similar) you would also see that the TCP connection as seen from the server does not have the original client address as source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not surprising. It is pretty much the definition of `NAT` (Network Address Translation). The VMs address is translated into on on the host.